# I can't get this template code working with my case (HTML to List)

Tags: android, html, json, listview, url

so I found this code on YouTube (Credit goes to "Indragni Soft Solutions") and I wanted to change it so it works with another webpage.
So it is pretty straight forward, there is a listview and I want the listview to display all of the people working here (http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/12-0-Amts-+und+Sprechstunden.html), but not the other things left of the office workers. To be as clear as possible: I want everything in the  tag. So everything that is in div#content-r should get into my list, with the picture next to it, and when the user taps on one of them, the full text should be displayed. But that doesn't really have to be necessary, as it would also work if there is just the name ontop, the picture left and the email under the name. So as I said, here is the code I tried:

```
package com.mrousavy.gemeindemuckendorfwipfing;

public class EcoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView mListView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lv);

    String strUrl = "http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/p/demo1/first.php/countries";  //This String should be http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/12-0-Amts-+und+Sprechstunden.html but I let it like this so you can see how the template-result looks
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);

}


private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        data = sb.toString();
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
    }

    return data;
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    String data = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
        listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
    }
}

private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter> {

    JSONObject jObject;

    @Override
    protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
            CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();
            countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("JSON Exception1", e.toString());
        }

        CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();

        List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;

        try {
            countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }

        String[] from = {"country", "flag", "details"};
        int[] to = {R.id.tv_country, R.id.iv_flag, R.id.tv_country_details};
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

        return adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
            String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
            ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

            HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put("flag_path", imgUrl);
            hm.put("position", i);

            imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
        }
    }
}

private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

        InputStream iStream = null;
        String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
        int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(imgUrl);

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
            File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_" + position + ".png");
            FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOutStream);
            fOutStream.flush();
            fOutStream.close();
            HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hmBitmap.put("flag", tmpFile.getPath());
            hmBitmap.put("position", position);
            return hmBitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
        String path = (String) result.get("flag");
        int position = (Integer) result.get("position");
        SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) mListView.getAdapter();
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);
        hm.put("flag", path);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

And here is the CountryJSONParser (Created by Aylar-HP):

```
package com.mrousavy.gemeindemuckendorfwipfing;

public class CountryJSONParser {

public List<HashMap<String, Object>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

    JSONArray jCountries = null;
    try {
        jCountries = jObject.getJSONArray("countries");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return getCountries(jCountries);
}

private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getCountries(JSONArray jCountries) {
    int countryCount = jCountries.length();
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> countryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> country = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < countryCount; i++) {
        try {
            country = getCountry((JSONObject) jCountries.get(i));
            countryList.add(country);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return countryList;
}

private HashMap<String, Object> getCountry(JSONObject jCountry) {
    HashMap<String, Object> country = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    String countryName = "";
    String flag = "";
    String language = "";
    String capital = "";
    String currencyCode = "";
    String currencyName = "";
    try {
        countryName = jCountry.getString("countryname");
        flag = jCountry.getString("flag");
        language = jCountry.getString("language");
        capital = jCountry.getString("capital");
        currencyCode = jCountry.getJSONObject("currency").getString("code");
        currencyName = jCountry.getJSONObject("currency").getString("currencyname");

        String details = "Language : " + language + "\n" +
                "Capital : " + capital + "\n" +
                "Currency : " + currencyName + "(" + currencyCode + ")";

        country.put("country", countryName);
        country.put("flag", R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        country.put("flag_path", flag);
        country.put("details", details);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return country;
}


}
```

So my question is; How can I change that code to work with my case? I have no clue how I just get the div#content-r out of the website, and then get it into my list.. :/ Thanks!